# How to fix "Error: Direct kernel connection broken"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've been using Jupyter notebooks in VSCode and it has worked fine for several months. Yesterday, I cleaned out a ton of my storage because it was cluttered and overfilled. Now my VSCode will either return an "Error: Direct kernel connection broken" or it will not install any of my previous packages.  Can anybody help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Switch kernel from .venv to default then switch it back again. then run all cells, not the current cell.

Comment: This worked for me, I didn't have to re-run all of the cells though. Just the one that I was on.

Answer (score 1):

I also stuck with the same problem :

1. Try to do this

pip install ipython

pip install ipykernel

2. If you already have a kernel installed, upgrade it

pip install --upgrade ipython

pip install --upgrade ipykernel

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

Switching the Jupyter server away from default and back again fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, please refer to the following:

1. Please try to reinstall the kernel module "ipykernel" required by'Jupyter' in the current python environment: (`pip install ipykernel`)
2. If it still doesn't work, please try to use other python environments and check if the python interpreter and "Python" extension and "Jupyter" extension are available.

Reference: [Jupyter in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) and [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).